# Simultaneous deployment to multiple AVDs

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-emulator

During development I need to ensure that my application runs on multiple Android versions. To do this I create and run multiple AVDs. Deployment to each of these individual AVDs can be time consuming and annoying.

Does anyone know of a way that I can simultaneously deploy to multiple AVDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the date of this posting, simultaneous deployment to multiple AVDs is not supported by the ADT plugin (18.0 to be exact).

You can expect this feature in a future ADT release, as Nikolay mentioned in his answer below.

Answer (score 1):

ADT 20 seems to support this, but I've never used it:

> Allow running on multiple devices with a single launch. The target tab
>   in the launch configuration dialog adds a new option which allows
>   launching on all connected devices, and a drop down allows the user to
>   further narrow down the list to just physical devices or just
>   emulators. (This applies only to Run configurations, not to
>   Debug/JUnit tests.)

http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview